# How to run application on url website instead of port 8080

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I followed the tutorials in AWS docs and using this video on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BIQks_drQHM . What I am trying to do is route traffic to verus-ai.com and [www.verus-ai.com](http://www.verus-ai.com). The only way I am able to run my application when I do yarn build and yarn serve is if I use the

Public IPv4 DNS
ec2-44-206-65-182.compute-1.amazonaws.com

with the port of 8080, essentially you can access it if you paste this into th e browser:  ec2-44-206-65-182.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080.

I want to be able to perform the same thing but with the domain I have i.e. verus-ai.com.

Domain Name: verus-ai.com

I was told from AWS support that the way everything is setup on Route 53 is correct and then problem resides on the application side.

I do not have much experiece with this part but there are 2 places in which the application is running on port 8080, specifically on the backend side

```
// set port, listen for requests
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});
```

and the front end side

```
export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:8080/api ",
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
  }
});
```

should I remove the port 8080?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to create a CNAME record in your DNS that points your domain name, or a subdomain of it, to the EC2 instance: `ec2-44-206-65-182.compute-1.amazonaws.com`. Ideally you would assign an ElasticIP to the instance first so the IP doesn't change later if you have to shut it down for any reason.

Second, You need to change the backend to run on port `80` instead of `8080`, because the default HTTP port is port `80` and that is the port that is used by web browsers when you enter an `http://` address without specifying a port.

Comment: Thank you so do I need to change anything on the front end side? Specifically the ` baseURL: "http://localhost:8080/api ",` part

Comment: I change the backend to run on port 80 but now the application is running on port 8081

Comment: `localhost:8080` will only work while you are running your application on your local laptop. You need to change it to `your.domain`.

Comment: As for your application running on port `8081` I have no idea what you are talking about because you didn't mention that anywhere in your question. Are you running two applications on ports `8080` and `8081`?

Comment: Thank you and apologies I am totally new at this. The backend application is running on port 80 but the front end is running on 8081.

Comment: Do answer your question on port 8081, to access my vue application I have to type in the ip-address of the ec2 instance and then specific port 8081 i.e. your_ec2_ip:8081

Comment: You need to have ALL services listening on port 80 if you don't want to include the port number in the URL. You should really be using an AWS load balancer for this, which would handle mapping port 80 on the load balancer to whatever port your servers/services are listening to, and would also make it easy to add an SSL certificate and use HTTPS on port 443.

Comment: Can I pay you for your time to help me with this? Or do you know someone that you could recommend me?

Comment: I changed everything to run on port 80 but now it is defaulting to port 1024 when I do `yarn serve`